# Compare date from source file and choose the most recent one

Tags: arrays, json, date, etl

I'm struggling with the following task. I have a source file in sft and I must run an ETL JOB to compare the dates in this file (DateA) with the ones in my database (DATEB).
Could you please help me setting this condition:

Condition 1) If Date A is null, leave Date B as it is
Condition 2) If Date A is more recent than Date B, replace Date B with Date A

I was thinking of something like that, but i can't finish it:

```
  "expression": "DATEA eq '' ? DATEB : Condition 2",
  "field": "data_CHANNEL_EMAIL_ACCEPTANCEDATE"
 }
```

Is that correct? How to I write the second condition?